# Does WebKit have an equivalent for the CSS pseudo-class -moz-drag-over?

Tags: css, webkit

The `:-moz-drag-over` pseudoclass (in Firefox) is used for styling an element that is a drop target (for drag and drop events) and that is currently being hovered by a dragged item. Does WebKit have an equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found the equivelant (YET) but you can use javascript dragging properties to get some control of a drag-over action.

[This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) shows how to do it using JavaScript. However, [this](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/) article presents a cross-browser solution (also, JS) that faces the issue and acts as a *common denominator.*